# jqgrid multiselect enable/ disable checkbox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to enable/disable the multiselect checkboxes (not hide the entire column) when a button is pressed(enters in edition mode).

my jqGrid version is 4.6.0.

[this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideMultiselectColumn.htm) is not what i'm looking for.

Is there an option for this or do I have to disable the row by row?

I've looked in the documentation at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

and I can't find something like what I wnat to do

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I did not understand what do you want...

Comment: I want to be able to disable the multiselect checkboxes without having to hide the entire column.

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/d6978ffbd674f555831c17ea0296feff/

Comment: The demo created by Paulo shows that one can still check disabled multiselect checkboxes indirectly by selection the rows. So the statement "I want to be able to disable the multiselect checkboxes without having to hide the entire column" allows still many interpretation what one want to have. Disabling of all checkboxes which have class `cbox` is not really difficult, but I still don't understand why one could need that and so which exactly requirements one have.

Comment: Can I post it as the answer?

Comment: yes you can,
that answerd my question